# You will be given a stream of integers

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

You will be given a stream of integers, and a integer k for window size, you will only receive the streams integers one by one. whenever you receive an integer, you have to return the maximum number among last k integers inclusive of current entry.

Interviewer was expecting O(N) Time + O(1) avg case space complexity solution for N tasks and integers are not given in a array, every time only one integer will be passed as input to your method.

I tried solving it but couldn't come up with O(N) solution. Can anybody tell me how can we do it.

Comment: I dont know if i follow understand your problem but if you do something like: First integer is max, next round you compare second int and previous max, and you update the max. Third round you compare the new integer with the max you already have calculated and update the max, and so on and so on. Wouldn't that suffice to solve what you were requested?

Comment: can you not simply store the current maximum? you only need to compare each integer to the current maximum, and overwrite with a new current maximum if necessary. maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: You guys missed the k window size.

Comment: What about additional memory max-min ?

Comment: Why does people still walk away from interviews without asking what the actual answer was? An interview should be both a chance to show what you can as well as a chance to learn. Walking away puzzled serves nobody.

Comment: Is *N* equal to `k`, or is *N* equal to the number of tasks that are concurrently running to perform this same exercise? You said "solution for N tasks".

Comment: How is this question getting so many upvotes? No shown attempt, no shown research... Are we forgetting how StackOverflow works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O(N) time is easy, but O(1) average space is impossible.

Here's what we absolutely need to store. For any number `x` we've seen in the last k inputs, if we've seen a bigger number since `x`, we can forget about `x`, since we'll never need to return it or compare it to anything again. If we haven't seen a bigger number since `x`, we need to store `x`, since we might have to return it at some point. Thus, we need to store the biggest number in the last k items, and the biggest after that, and the biggest after that, all the way up to the current input. In the worst case, the input is descending, and we always need to store all of the last k inputs. In the average case, at any time, we'll need to keep track of O(log(k)) items; however, the peak memory usage will be greater than this.

The algorithm we use is to simply keep track of a deque of all the numbers we just said we need to store, in their natural, descending order, along with when we saw them*. When we receive an input, we pop everything lower than it from the right of the deque and push the input on the right of the deque. We peek-left, and if we see that the item on the left is older than the window size, we pop-left. Finally, we peek-left, and the number we see is the sliding window maximum.

This algorithm processes each input in amortized constant time. The only part of processing an input that isn't constant time is the part where we pop-right potentially all of the deque, but since each input is only popped once over the course of the algorithm, that's still amortized constant. Thus, the algorithm takes O(N) time to process all input.

*If N is ridiculously huge, we can keep track of the indices at which we saw things mod k to avoid overflow problems.

Comment: @NikoDrašković: Just track the index at which we saw each item along with the item. I've edited the answer to make that more explicit. It doesn't change the space complexity, since the size of a queue item is still constant.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `k` is small and not part of the scaling parameter *N* (the question says *N* is the number of **Tasks**, but it's not quite clear what that means).

1. Implement a FIFO, with insertion and deletion costing *O(1)* in time, and *O(k)* in memory.
2. Also implement a `max` variable
3. Pop the oldest value, see if it is equal to `max`, if is (which unlikely for all values of `max`), then run over `k` elements of FIFO and recalculate `max`, otherwise don't. Amortized, this is *O(1)*.
4. Compare new value with `max` and update `max` if necessary.
5. push `max` into FIFO.

Then time is *O(1)* and memory is *O(k+1)*. I don't see how you not have storage requirements at least *O(k)*. The time to process *N* integers is them *O(N)*.

Comment: Step 3 runs into problems if the input is largely descending. That seems like a fairly likely scenario.

Comment: @user2357112 - you are right. Then worst case is then *O(k)*.  If *k* is order 1, then I guess it doesn't matter. You solution is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, most interviewers will consider memory O(k) to be O(1).

Given that little detail, you can just implement a ring buffer :

```
int numbers[k]; // O(1) because k is constant
int i = 0, next_number;
while (next_number= new_number()) {
    numbers[i % k]= next_number;
    i++;
    if (i >= k) {
        int max= MIN_INT;
        for (int j= 0; j < k; j++) { // O(1) because k is constant
            if (numbers[j] > max) max = numbers[j];
        }
        yield(max);
    }
}
```

Of course, if they don't consider O(k) to be O(1), there is no solution to the problem and they either screwed up their question or were hoping for you to say that the question is wrong.

*A fifo/deque is usually faster here (for k above some number), I'm just demonstrating the simplest answer to a dumb question.*

Answer (score -2):

This is the answer that comes to mind (C++)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter K: " << endl;
    int K;
    cin >> K;

    cout << "Enter stream." << endl;

    int n, counter = 1, max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    while (cin >> n){
        if (counter % K == 0)
           max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
        if (n > max) 
           max = n;
        cout << max << endl;
        ++counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this solution still uses O(N) memory, and the question is about using O(1) memory.

Comment: I don't think this works... how is `counter % K == 0` adequate to check last K entries? This only seems to reset max to minimum every Kth entry.

Comment: this solution would not get the max value from the LAST k values. It would require to save the values in a "circular buffer" of k size and on each round "if (counter % K == 0)" to lookup the buffer for the current max value.